# passing `this` through a function as a variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, function, variables, this

I want to pass the element doing the action through to a function, but not sure how to do it.

```
$('.report_chart_enquiries').click(function(){
    showing_barcharts(this);
}

function showing_barcharts(elem) {
     $(elem).addClass('report_chart_current');
}

<div class="report_chart_enquiries">Enquiries</div>
```

This is how I thought it would work, but not doing anything. Is it even possible?

Comment: Could you share a minimal HTML?

Comment: added some html

Comment: Is this your exact JS? It has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Re-check your code js:

```
$('.report_chart_enquiries').click(function(){
    showing_barcharts(this);
}); //you mistaked there

function showing_barcharts(elem) {
    $(elem).addClass('report_chart_current');
}
```

This is a demo link https://jsfiddle.net/f10cpkyd/

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass a named function to click handler and use a parameter with `.target` to get the element that triggered the event

```js
$('.report_chart_enquiries').click(showing_barcharts)

function showing_barcharts(elem) {
  $(elem.target).addClass('report_chart_current');
}
```

```css
.report_chart_current {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="report_chart_enquiries">Enquiries</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code works, try this more efficiently:

```
$(document).on('click', '.report_chart_enquiries', function(){
    showing_barcharts(this);
}); 

function showing_barcharts(elem) {
    $(elem).addClass('report_chart_current');
}
```

$(document) will ensure that your code always works.